# Is there a way to change the date format in multiple XML files at once using Oxygen?

Tags: xml

I use Oxygen to edit XML files doing a variety of things in project mode. But I have been unable to find a way to take multiple XML files that all contain a  tag, and currently all contain text values for dates in mm/dd/yyyy format, and change them to yyyy/mm/dd format. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd be happy to use a simple XSLT to do this as well if that's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using oXygen you can use Saxon and XSLT 2.0. This will allow you to use [`collection()`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html).

Example...

**XML Input** (two XML files in "some_dir" similar to what's below)

```
<doc>
    <test>05/08/2018</test>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="input_dir" select="'some_dir'"/>
  <xsl:param name="output_dir" select="'another_dir'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="init">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="collection(concat($input_dir,'?select=*.xml'))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/doc">
    <xsl:result-document href="{concat($output_dir,'/',tokenize(base-uri(),'/')[last()])}">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(normalize-space(),'/')"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="($tokens[3],$tokens[1],$tokens[2])" separator="/"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (two XML files in "another_dir" similar to what's below)

```
<doc>
   <test>2018/05/08</test>
</doc>
```

Note that the stylesheet expects an initial template specified.

In the XSLT Debugger...

[image]

You can specify the initial template in the Saxon configuration of oXygen...

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the answer. You'll have to forgive my inexperience, I've only ever worked with XSLT one way, and that is by opening my source XML, going to Document>Transformation and then choosing my XSLT and Output path.

Comment: @KellyJ.Applegate - Do you have oXygen Author, Developer, or Editor? My screenshot is of the XSLT Debugger only available in either Developer or Editor. If you only have Author, I could show you an example of running the stylesheet using Saxon from the command line (java command line).

Comment: I have Oxygen Editor.

Comment: @KellyJ.Applegate - If that's the case, open the XSLT file, go to the XSLT Debugger (button is in the upper right; see first screenshot), and click the configuration button to set the initial template in Saxon (second screenshot). You'll also have to update the input_dir and output_dir param values in the stylesheet (or set them by clicking the configure parameters button (wrench and nut icon)). Then click the blue right-arrow icon to run the transform.